If $A_n$ are measurable, and $\chi_{A_n} \rightarrow f$ in measure, then $f = \chi_A$ for some measurable $A$.
Question: If $A_n$ are measurable, $\mu(A_n) < \infty$, and $\chi_{A_n} \rightarrow f$ in measure, then $f = \chi_A$ almost everywhere for some measurable $A$.
Approach: If $\chi_{A_n} \rightarrow f$ in measure, then there exists a subsequence along which we have almost sure convergence, i.e., $\chi_{A_{n_k}} \rightarrow f$ a.s. This implies that $\limsup \chi_{A_{n_k}} = \liminf \chi_{A_{n_k}} = f$ almost everywhere, but we know that $\limsup \chi_{A_{n_k}} = \chi_{\limsup \chi_{A_{n_k}}}$ (and similarly for $\liminf$). Thus, $f = \chi_{\limsup \chi_{A_{n_k}}} $.
If the above is correct, where in the above proof is the requirement $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ needed?

$\mu (A_n) <\infty$ is not needed. But you should say $f=\chi_A$ a.e. in the title.

Your proof is essentially correct. It needs the minor change in the conclusion that $f=\chi_A$ a.e. and the condition $\mu(A_n)< \infty$ is not needed, as @geetha290krm correctly pointed out.
